# How to get a list of Herald Rule regular expressions from Phabricator with REST API?

Tags: regex, git, rest, phabricator

There is git repository and Phabricator using for code review.
And there is need to get a list of Herald rule regular expressions in order to define which files of repo are not covered with Herald rules.

It there any way to reach it with external or Phabricator internal tools?

Comment: Please include link to the repo, and try to post code that you want to use to achieve your goals. Also,  your question doesn’t clearly state what you need.

Comment: Why are you asking link of repo. This question is about Phabricator.
I just need to get a list of Herald rules and extract regular expression of each of them. A list of regular expressions is needed to check a coverage file system by regular expressions. Is there any way to automate extraction of Herald rules from Phabricator?

Answer (score 0):

There were [a proposed feature](https://secure.phabricator.com/T7651) of Phabricator API asking that, closed as WONTFIX by lack of use case. You could reopen the task and add your use case if you still need it.

The original reporter even wrote the code to implement an herald.queryrules method in conduit API. You can so apply [this patch](https://secure.phabricator.com/D12140) against your Phabricator install and then try it:

`echo '{}' | arc call-conduit herald.queryrules`